# How to hide textField in report generated in specified format?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using the JasperReports 4.7,
 Trying to hide a text field while exporting to pdf,xsl. I've tried the using of
`net.sf.jasperreports.export.{format}.exclude.origin.{suffix}.{arbitrary_name}` property.

It didn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use another property: ***net.sf.jasperreports.export.{format}.exclude.key.{keyvalue}***, where the *keyvalue* is element's key to exclude.

#### Example.

The *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="exclude_textfield_sample" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="5207ad85-202f-4b93-ba07-39185c10d443">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.exclude.key.tfToHideInPDF"/>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="11c36fdc-c1ff-4901-a2cc-f939439c83f2" x="87" y="30" width="150" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Text field not to exclude"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="8524232f-a769-478d-9a6d-643548e6555f" key="tfToHideInPDF" x="269" y="30" width="187" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Text field to exclude"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

In this report I've placed two *textFields*: first with *key="tfToHideInPDF"* to exclude in *pdf* file and the second for showing in all report's formats.

The report's design (in *iReport*):

[image]

The *rtf* document generated with *RTF Preview* in *iReport* is:

[image]

And the *dpf* document generated with *PDF Preview* in *iReport* is:

[image]

---

If you want to hide *textField* additionally in *rtf* format, for example, you should just add another property: ***`<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.rtf.exclude.key.tfToHideInPDF"/>`***. And so on.

Comment: can we hide this field when print the document?

Comment: `can we hide this field when print the document? ` - What do you mean?

Comment: I've bottom and top link in report.when printing the document those link should not print. alex

Comment: `I've bottom and top link in report` - What is it? If it is an element - yes, you can. `when printing the document those link should not print` - If you are talking about generating report in some format - yes, you can

Comment: i'm talking about take the hard copy of the report.