# How to remove blank row in Jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

This question is in continuation : [How to hide textField in report generated in specified format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18585154/how-to-hide-textfield-in-report-generated-in-specified-format)

depending on some conditions when all rows are blank how to remove those ?
in my case one column hiding because (print non repeated rows), and two columns are hidden becase of given condition (pdf.exclude) so now row is blank.
I want to remove this blank row. Can you suggest ?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you must be using Textfield, and navigate to properties then select Textfiled tab and check blnk when null checkbox, If you want to remove the line itself from common tab tick remove line when blank.
that's about it

Comment: I tried this, used remove line when blank and selected blnk when null check still not working. In my case column value hiding because of exclude.pdf , in case of csv it is showing.  I think this is the reason it is showing one blank row, my question is to remove this blank row in case of pdf. where as in case csv it ishould as as it is with row information.